# Python: How do i split the file?

Tags: python

I have this txt file which is ls -R of etc directory in a linux system. Example file:

```
etc:  
ArchiveSEL  
xinetd.d

etc/cmm:  
CMM_5085.bin  
cmm_sel  
storage.cfg  

etc/crontabs:  
root

etc/pam.d:  
ftp    
rsh  

etc/rc.d:  
eth.set.sh  
rc.sysinit  

etc/rc.d/init.d:  
cmm  
functions  
userScripts  

etc/security:  
access.conf  
console.apps  
time.conf

etc/security/console.apps:  
kbdrate

etc/ssh:  
ssh_host_dsa_key  
sshd_config  

etc/var:  
setUser  
snmpd.conf

etc/xinetd.d:  
irsh  
wu-ftpd
```

I would like to split it by subdirectories into several files. example files would be like this:  etc.txt, etcCmm.txt, etcCrontabs.txt, etcPamd.txt, ...
Can someone give me a python code that can do that?
Notice that the subdirectory lines end with ':', but i'm just not smart enough to write the code. some examples would be appreciated. 
thank you :)

Comment: If you don't know anything about Python, the most decent thing to do is to read up on it and understand what's going on. Head down to Python docs to learn about Python. Saying things like "just not smart enough" is just an excuse.

Comment: hey guys, cut me some slack. i just added that line to be modest. i did try looking for more than half a day for an example or solution before i decided to post the question. Would appreciate more constructive help next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this? `re.M` generates a multiline regular expression which can match several lines, and the last part just iterates over the matches and creates the files...

```
import re

data = '<your input data as above>' # or open('data.txt').read()
results = map(lambda m: (m[0], m[1].strip().splitlines()),
    re.findall('^([^\n]+):\n((?:[^\n]+\n)*)\n', data, re.M))

for dirname, files in results:
    f = open(dirname.replace('/', '')+'.txt', 'w')
    for line in files:
        f.write(line + '\n')
    f.close()
```

Comment: @Marius Gedminas: why do you think so? I think it's easy to read :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do it line-by-line. if a `line.endswith(":")` then you are in a new subdirectory. From then on, each line is a new entry into your subdirectory, until another line ends with `:`.

From my understanding, you just want to split one textfile into several, ambiguously named, text files.

So you'd see if a line ends with `:`. then you open a new text file, like `etcCmm.txt`, and every line that you read from the source text, from that point on, you write into`etcCmm.txt`. When you encounter another line that ends in `:`, you close the previously opened file, create a new one, and continue.

I'm leaving a few things for you to do yourself, such as figuring out what to call the text file, reading a file line-by-line, etc.

Comment: It's legal for filenames to end in `:`. Better to check for the `/`

Comment: but he has `etc` in there with no `/`. I guess he could just check for double-line breaks

Answer (score 0):

use regexp like '.*:'. 
use file.readline().
use loops.

Answer (score 0):

If Python is not a must, you can use this one liner

```
awk '/:$/{gsub(/:|\//,"");fn=$0}{print $0 > fn".txt"}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

Read the file into memory (`myfile = open(filename).read()` should do).

Then split the file along the delimiters:

```
import re
myregex = re.compile(r"^(.*):[ \t]*$", re.MULTILINE)
arr = myregex.split(myfile)[1:] # dropping everything before the first directory entry
```

Then convert the array to a dict, removing unwanted characters along the way:

```
mydict = dict([(re.sub(r"\W+","",k), v.strip()) for (k,v) in zip(arr[::2], arr[1::2])])
```

Then write the files:

```
for name,content in mydict.iteritems():
    output = open(name+".txt","w")
    output.write(content)
    output.close()
```